# How is backgroundColor handled for UIView in Objective_C?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview, background-color

I have been playing with some of [Apple's example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318) for customizing UITableViewCells. I have run into some weird behavior that has left me completely confused about how backgroundColor works.

The following code is a much reduced version of Apple's example custom UIView within custom UITableViewCell. The init function sets the background color to purple and then the drawRect sets the background color to green. I would expect to never see purple, but that is all I see. Through NSLog statements I know that the init method is being called for each of the cells, followed by drawRect being called for each of the cells. The green setting seems to be ignored. If I call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` any time after the initial load, the background is correctly set to green.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    counter = 0;
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this would be happening like this?

Comment: Sorry, but all I see is green, no purple. Would you like to paste your UITableViewDataSource codes as well?

Comment: if you look at the apple link above and look at the 5th example, that is the project I started with. The only changes were to reduce the CustomeTableViewCell down to basically what you see above as it is the smallest amount of code I could get that still shows the issue I was seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `-drawRect:` implementation doesn't actually do any drawing, so it's not going to change anything itself.

Presumably, the drawing is being done by a layer associated with your view. It looks like, in your environment, the background-colored layer is doing its drawing before your `-drawRect:` method is called. When the layer redraws, your `-drawRect:` method also happens to be called. So, after you change the background color, you don't see any changes till the background layer draws again, which you can tell happened because your `-drawRect:` gets called again.

If you want the color change to apply immediately, you need to mark your view as needing display, so that it will completely redraw with the changed background color.

Comment: My example above is a greatly reduced version of what was there. In the original version -drawRect was setting the text in a number of Labels and that worked just fine. It was only the background that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I am interested in what you said about it not actually doing any drawing. I thought that was its whole point. Is -drawRect not pretty similar to a windows OnPaint() call? Is the backgroundColor special in that it doesn't always get rendered even thought it has been set?

Sorry if this should be obvious. After 10 years of Win development, I am just now trying to wrap my head around the way Objective-C behaves.

Comment: @JGoForth "Your" in this case was the specific example of `-drawRect:` you provided. In general, `-drawRect:` will do some drawing. The `backgroundColor` is generally set from *outside* a drawing function, in an `-init`, `-viewDidLoad`, or action method (e.g. on touch up inside some view). The background color is rendered by the framework, but where in exactly in relation to `-drawRect:` is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath ??

Why did you not try using

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
```