# Setting backgroundColor doesn't seem to work on a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have some code that tries to set the backgroundColor in a UIView from an Image but all I see is black screen. Here is what I did -

1. Have a `UIViewController` class and `UIView` class
2. The `UIView` class has a `drawRect` function.
3. In the `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad` function create the `UIView` class
4. After that the `drawRect` in the `UIView` is called.

Here is the code for the `UIView`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *backGround = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
    self.backgroundColor = backGround;
}
```

Verified in the debugger that the `backGround` object is not nil after execution. Also tested the test.png file exists and I can create a `UIImageView` with it.

I see that the result is the same if I set the `backgroundColor` in the `initWithFrame` function instead of the `drawRect()`

The reason I want to set the `backgroundColor` is I am drawing a board game and I want to use the image as the background. That way I can just draw the lines (board) on the image.

Comment: just try in the viewDidLoad **self.view.backgroundColor = backGround;**

Comment: `[self.view setBackgroundColor:<#(UIColor *)#>];`

Comment: @KumarKl -- how is this technically different from what I did? I am guessing there is some knowledge here I am missing.

Comment: @KumarKl - That worked! If you can answer my question as a regular answer I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try out this in the `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIColor *backGround = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
        self.view.backgroundColor = backGround;

//.....
}
```

**EDIT:**

*For your problem :*

the drawing is being done by a layer associated with your view. It looks like, in your environment, the background-colored layer is doing its drawing before your `-drawRect:` method is called. When the layer redraws, your `-drawRect:` method also happens to be called. So, after you change the background color, you don't see any changes till the background layer draws again, which you can tell happened because your -drawRect: gets called again. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047346/set-uiview-backgroundcolor-with-drawrect) && [Check for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229636/how-is-backgroundcolor-handled-for-uiview-in-objective-c))

Answer (score 2):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
        UIColor *backGround = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
        self.backgroundColor = backGround;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Changing the background in **drawRect** won't work. Any changes to it must be done in the **init** method.

Answer (score 0):

In drawRect method you should not set background. You have to do drawing, which you want to draw in view. Background view is separate view. If you want to set the background view within your custom view, do it in init method or else you can do it in your view controller(anywhere).